# TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined(sequelize)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I did refer to similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795953/typeerror-cannot-read-property-findall-of-undefined-expressjs) but here while debugging I am getting `models` as empty. I am clueless as to why is this happening. DB table is `Users`.

controllers/user.js:

```
const models = require('../models');
const User = models.Users;
exports.getAllUsers = (req,res,next) => {
  console.log(models);
  console.log(User);
User.findAll({
  attributes: attributesUser
}).then(users => {
  console.log(users);
  res.status(200).json({
    data: users
  });
});
}
```

models/user.js:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        len: [4, 255]
      }
    },
    middleName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        len: [4, 255]
      }
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        len: [4,255]
      }
    },
    mobile: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      validate:{
        len: [10,15],
        isNumeric:{
          msg:"Invalid Mobile Number"
        }
      }
    },
    address: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false
    },
    dob: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull:false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true
      },
      set(email){
        this.setDataValue("email",email.toString().toLowerCase());
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false
    },
    gender: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false
    },
    isDisabled: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false
    },
    lastLoginTime: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull:false
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    deletedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
  }, {});
  Users.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Users.belongsTo(models.UserType, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: "userTypeId",
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
    Users.belongsTo(models.Qualification, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: "qualificationId",
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
    Users.belongsTo(models.Organization, {
      foreignKey: "organizationId",
      allowNull: false
    });
  };
  return Users;
};
```

Output:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined
    at exports.getAllUsers (/mnt/part1/projects/Video_Coaching/backend-v2/controllers/user.js:87:10)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mnt/part1/projects/Video_Coaching/backend-v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/mnt/part1/projects/Video_Coaching/backend-v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/mnt/part1/projects/Video_Coaching/backend-v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mnt/part1/projects/Video_Coaching/backend-v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /mnt/part1/projects/Video_Coaching/backend-v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
```

Comment: models.Users which you are using is not defined as module.exports in model is the endpoint not 'Users' in its function. try using models.user when defining User in your controller.

Comment: can you post your `models.js` file? I need more information about to help you

Comment: @ShaahinShemshian I have tried two other ways `const User = require('../models/user');`  and also the one you told but both the error is same

Comment: `@A.Granados` I have updated the question on your request. please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the models didn't had sequelize instance.

While sequelize created a index.js file under models/ but I commented that file at the start of the project because it gave me errors. I just un-commented the file and created models like this `const models = require('../models/index');`.

So one should require `models/index.js` to get sequelize and DataTypes instance where one is going to use models, not `models/user.js.`